# JQuery: adding attributes of Elements that appended

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried to access the attribute of an element that appended to an element that it appended too.

".chat-private" appended too.
how can i do this?
this is my script code:

```
$('#users-list').on('click', '.chat-private', function () {
    $("#dialog-area").append("<div class='dialog'><h4>Chat</h4><textarea cols='30' rows='10' id='chatarea'></textarea><input type='text' id='chattext'></div>");
    var userid = $(this).attr("userid");
    $('#dialog').attr('userid', userid);
    });
```

and HTML:

```
<div id="users-list">
    users:
</div>
<div id="dialogs-area">
</div>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: It appears you may be using [class selectors](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) for `id`s (`$(".dialog-area")` vs. `id="dialogs-area"`) and [id selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) for `class`es (`$('#dialog')` vs `class='dialog'`).

Comment: Beware of duplicate IDs!

Comment: Why -1, i like to know!

Comment: -1 What is this meant to do: `var userid = $(this).attr("userid");
    $('#dialog').attr('userid', userid);`? And where is `class="dialog-area"`?

Comment: @user3558931: i edited. the userid attr is in chat-private element that i got that. thanks

Comment: see here http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/45/ this works.

Comment: I think you already fixed your code in question, there is no need of adding as answer, but you shoudn't fix problem in your question otherwise other viewers may confuse.

Comment: ok, i changed it to first place mode.

Comment: @undefined I've given a fiddle in my comment, which is working for OP, can you just upvote that, so other viewers can see that easily. I think OP can't vote.

Comment: @undefined I don't know what I was thinking, added as an answer, sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your div has a class `dialog` and in selector you are saying `#dialog`. You should say `.dialog`.

```
$('#dialog').attr('userid', userid);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/C7JJM/45/)

And you should avoid adding custom `attributes` to elements, use [*data-attributes*](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) inroduced in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Add id's to your html strings. When you append the code, you can then reference them later by id to manipulate them. Just be careful - chicken before the egg and what not.

http://jsfiddle.net/qrggj2go/

```
<div id="test"/>

$("#test").append("<button id='test2'>Hi</button>");
$("#test2").click(function(){
    $("#test2").hide();
});
```